# How to use mongoose schema to get data and send it to client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to nodejs so I have app that is connected with mongodb now i have api `getAllDiagrams` in router that should send all diagram data to client, The approach i am trying to implement is i want to call db from controller and once i have data i will require that in router and send it to client , Below code i could not make it work and getting error `then is not defined`. Any idea what is implemented wrong or any better way to use this approach.

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/develop-modeler');
require('./server/api/diagram/diagram.model.js');

mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error('MongoDB connection error: ' + err);
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.listen(8760, function() {
    console.log('I am listening 8760...');
})
```

diagram.controller.js

```
 var Diagram = require('./diagram.model');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    module.exports = function index(req, res) {
  Diagram.find({}, function(err, result) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log('Response from controller', result);
      return res.send(result);
    }
  });
}
```

diagram.model.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

/*var User = require('../user/user.model.js');
var Group = require('../group/group.model.js');*/

var DiagramSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: String,
  owner: {type: String, ref:'User'},
  groups: [{type: String, ref: 'Group'}],
  users: [{type: String, ref: 'User'}],
  string: String
});

 mongoose.model('Diagram', DiagramSchema);
```

router.js

```
var express = require('express');
var controller = require('./diagram.controller');

var router = express.Router();

console.log('THis is in router',controller.index());
router.get('/getAllDiagram',controller.index());

/*router.get('/', controller.index);*/

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Why yu used `Diagram.find.then` in your query is there any promises are you using?

Comment: I am not using any promises, All of code is pasted in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I am seeing you are not using any promises stuff but expect to return a promise in your query,.But it is  promise way of work that's why you are getting this error

```
 var express = require('express');
var controller = require('./diagram.controller');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/getAllDiagram',controller.index());
```

---

```
module.exports = function index(req, res) {
  Diagram.find({}, function(err, result) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log('Response from controller', result);
      return res.send(result);
    }
  });
}
```

Update your schema like this

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

/*var User = require('../user/user.model.js');
var Group = require('../group/group.model.js');*/

var DiagramSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  text: String,
  owner: {type: String, ref:'User'},
  groups: [{type: String, ref: 'Group'}],
  users: [{type: String, ref: 'User'}],
  string: String
});

 module.exports=mongoose.model('Diagram', DiagramSchema);
```

Comment: TypeError: Diagram.find is not a function

Comment: Can you remove `new` keyword in schema and then try?

Comment: same error `TypeError: Diagram.find is not a function`

Comment: ahh you didn't export your model

Comment: add this line at end in your schema 
 `module.exports=mongoose.model('Diagram', DiagramSchema);`

Comment: yes it solve controller issue and prints data in controller but my router is still not getting the data from controller so i can send it to client.

Comment: Yes, since you are not doing anything to send it route

Comment: return your result in your query. but you need to write right code

Comment: controller.index is not returning anything in router, but if i add controller() in app.js i see the data.

Comment: Can you edit your question what have you tried yet? it's very common way to get the response

Comment: Don't use `()` direc call controller.index